# copy THREE.js matrix from object

Tags: javascript, matrix, three.js

i need to to same matrix mulitiply in Three.js. I had an Object3D and i get the right matrix to console.log when doing this:

```
  console.log (scene.getObjectByName( "Pointer" ).matrix)
```

the result is like:

> T…E.Matrix4 {elements: Float32Array[16]}
>   elements: Float32Array[16] 0: 11: 02: 03: 04: 05: 16: 07: 08: 09: 0 10: 11 1: 0 12: -150 13: 0 14: 0 15: 1

note here that the 12th element have the value -150 (after a obj.translationX(-150)).

```js
      var newMat = new THREE.Matrix4();
      console.log(scene.getObjectByName("Pointer").matrix.elements)
      // output: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
      newMat = newMat.copy(scene.getObjectByName("Pointer").matrix);
      console.log(newMat);
      // output:elements: Float32Array[16] 1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1
```

giving back an identiy matrix (meaning the 12th element is: 0)

Whats is wrong here?

**UPDATE:** inside the renderloop... newMat.copy(...).. works fine!

Comment: are you on the object name Pointer calling updateMatrix first I am seeing this is the container object like THREE.Object3D

Comment: i tried object ubdateMatrix()... but this didnt helped. Yes Pointer is an containerObject..where i put  on loadedJsonObject

Comment: child_clone.applyMatrix(container[i].object3d.children[j].parent.matrix); // this is bad
child_clone.applyMatrix(container[i].object3d.children[j].parent.parent.matrix);
child_clone.applyMatrix(container[i].object3d.children[j].parent.parent.parent.matrix);
child_clone.applyMatrix(container[i].object3d.children[j].parent.parent.parent.parent.matrix);
child_clone.updateMatrixWorld()
moral is do apply the matrix to your child container from parent and then updateMatrixWorld ( actually my matrix are not at all updated reason is I was creating my own object instead of three.js Object3D container

Answer (score 0):

three.js will update the object matrix when it render the page according the object position, scale, rotation. So when you set the object matrix, it will sooner be rewrited. 
To manually set the object matrix, you have to set autoupdate to false.

```
object.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
```

then use the your code.

```
  var newMat = new THREE.Matrix4();
  console.log(scene.getObjectByName("Pointer").matrix.elements)
  // output: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
  newMat = newMat.copy(scene.getObjectByName("Pointer").matrix);
  console.log(newMat);
```

Comment: Do not set `matrixAutoUpdate = false` unless you are familiar with the inner-workings of the library and understand the consequences of doing so.