# Image will not refresh in a camera scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

Image will not refresh in a scene.
Using Javascript, Three and CSS3DRenderer on the client within chrome.
I have an image embedded in a scene via a THREE.Object3D and when the image is updated on the server, the image will not update in the scene. I do use a cache breaking technique and proved to myself that the browser cache was being updated.
In summary:

```
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000); 

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var renderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var element = document.createElement('div');
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = images[i].src+'?t='+new Date().getTime(); // cache busting technique
element.appendChild(img);
var object = new THREE.CSS3DObject(element);
scene.add(object);
```

The image is displayed just fine.
It is then updated on the server with the same cache busting technique and nothing changes in the scene.
I’ve tried to update the scene with a variety of statements like:

```
scene.remove(x);
scene.add(x);
camera.updateProjectionMatrix(); // didn't do anything I noticed
renderer.render(scene, camera);  //
```

Any clues would be helpful
Thanks

Comment: images[i].src+'?t='+new Date().getTime();   Here I'm not understantd

Comment: thanks for taking the time to look at this question. It turns out that image src property was being updated before the server had a chance to update the picture. So the old picture was being read into the browser's cache. I had to delay the src update for 2 seconds to see the change.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it did, but three.js automatically calculate the object matrix accordig object size, position and some other parameters every few milliseconds, then override the matrix you set. If you want to set matrix, you have to config the object matrix auto calculation false.

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40229987/6521116).

Comment: Are you saying it displayed the changed image? Because I didn't see it change. I don't want to override or manually set anything if I don;t have to. But I can't seem to cause it to update the image being displayed on screen.

Comment: If you issue is caused by this, you will not see any difference, for the recalculate at a high frequency.

Comment: I'm a little confused here, what is the x in your scene, and your projection and scene not changed, why the image would change.